# Scope reading changes with amplitude scale

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a low frequency (70Hz) sine wave being measured by a 1x probe on a (lower-end) Siglent SDS1052DL, and I get a roughly a reading I expect.  However, when I change the amplitude scale, the reading changes as much as 5%: 1.22Vpp at 200mV divisions, 1.28Vpp at 500mV div, 1.30Vpp at 1V div, 1.36Vpp at 2V div.  I hear an audible 'click' when changing from 200mV to 500mV scale, so I am assuming the circuitry is changing in that case.

Is this normal for lower end scopes?  It matters when trying to do things like accurately measure the output impedance of a sig gen.

Comment: You usually only have a resolution of 8 bits, even in high end scopes, so naturally switching to a range with 10 times the scale will give a different reading.

Comment: @Arsenal Does that mean the highest resolution is always the most accurate?  (Except when the resolution is so high that the peaks go off screen and the measurement gets clipped)

Comment: Its a bit like heisenberg uncertainty principle: you can either measure fast, or measure accurate, or pay ginormous amounts of money to do both.

Comment: @Arsenal Assuming this scope has a range of 8 divisions and 8-bit measurements, 200mV divs has resolution 1.6/256 = 6.25mV, and 500mV divs has resolution 4/256 = 15.6mV.

Comment: That sounds right - but that is only resolution. Accuracy is usually also dependent on the range. Somewhere buried in the data sheet of the oscilloscope. And I'd expect the smallest range to provide the most accurate reading (as long as that setting does not disturb the thing I'm measuring).

Comment: datasheet accuracy indicates +/-3% neglecting noise. +0.2div+100mv  ...Do Self Cal operation?